# Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've been working on a basic forum for our site. I've ran into some trouble with a query using PDO with the error:

```
 number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

This is caused by this fllowing code:

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE topics SET replies=:replies, lastposter=:poster, lastpostdate=:date WHERE id = :id"); 
$stmt1->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt1->bindParam(':replies', $replies);
$stmt1->bindParam(':poster', $poster);
$stmt1->bindParam(':date', $date);
$stmt1->execute();
```

`$id`, `$replies` and `$date` are integers, `$poster` is a string. I have a similar query above that works just fine which is as follows:

```
 $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE main SET topics = :topics, lastposter = :poster, lastpostdate = :date WHERE id = :id");
```

Comment: What is the schema of your topics table?

Comment: `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `forumid` int(11) unsigned,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `subject` text NOT NULL,
  `poster` text NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastposter` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lastpostdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `replies` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,

Comment: Did you cut and paste the code exactly from your script? I don't see a problem in the code in the question. This error means that there's a mismatch between the placeholders in the prepared statement and the ones that you bound with `bindParam` -- check your code for typos.

Comment: As far as I'm aware yes, all the vars are correct same with the sql parts

Comment: Just went through every var and bindparam and they all match the SQL and each other. Is there anyway I can see exactly which one is causing the error? The exact error I'm getting is Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens